# How can I get auto generated keys and set the resultset type?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, resultset

I have this SQL statement:

```
con = cpds.getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            SQL = "INSERT INTO person(accountID,addressID,lastName,firstName,middleName,suffix,gender,birthDate, [language], ethinicity) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

What I want to be able to do is get the generated keys for this statement. Now I have done this before, but without setting the resultset typescroll parameter. It seems that there is no argument that does this either:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
```

What I want to know is this: How can I set the resultset type to typescroll insensitive AND get generated keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Statement#getGeneratedKeys()` returns a `ResultSet` that you can use to retrieve the *keys* as

```
ResultSet rsKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rsKeys.next()) {
    person.setId(rsKeys.getLong(1));
}
```

> How can I set the resultset type to typescroll insensitive AND get generated keys?

Doing this doesn't make sense because you can expect to retrieve *keys* only after doing an *insert*. While you would want to set the *scroll* type only for a *resultset* i.e. after a *query*. So, the two things are mutually exclusive and hence the API obviously doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

[`statement.getGeneratedKeys();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) would help